# Variable 'A' or 'B' as Variable 'C'

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to get the email address of a user either from Active Directory or if the PC is not a domain member, to then prompt for the user's email. I think I have a pretty good start, but now I'm stuck.
I'm trying to populate `mail.From` with whatever is determined by the `DirectoryServices` query. I am trying to use an IF/ELSE, but maybe I'm WAAAY off track.

Oh... Did I mention I'm a noob?

Here's what I have so far...

```
'Get current users email address from AD
If currentADUser IsNot Nothing Then
    ' user exists
    Dim MailUser = userEmail
    UserEmailAdd.Hide()
    LblEmail.Hide()
Else
    ' user does *not* exist
    Dim MailUser As String = UserEmailAdd.Text
    UserEmailAdd.Show()
    LblEmail.Show()
End If
mail.From = New MailAddress(MailUser)
```

Comment: What *is* this doing, then? And how is that different than what you want it to do?

Comment: You are declaring a `MailUser` variable inside each branch of the `If ... Then ... Else` and attempting to use that variable outside its scope by assign `mail.From`.  Instead, either declare `MailUser` before/outside the `If ... Then ... Else` or assign `mail.From` in both branches.  Also, you are referencing `userEmail` in the first branch, which seems like it should be some property of `currentADUser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a vb expert but you need something like this

```
Dim MailUser As String 

If currentADUser IsNot Nothing Then
    ' user exists
    MailUser = userEmail
    UserEmailAdd.Hide()
    LblEmail.Hide()
Else
    ' user does *not* exist
    MailUser = UserEmailAdd.Text
    UserEmailAdd.Show()
    LblEmail.Show()
End If
mail.From = New MailAddress(MailUser)
```

Comment: An important nuance here is the `MailUser` variable's scope. Scope is the time window when a variable "exists". If you declare a variable inside a `If` block, it's scope is limited to this block. In the original code snippet, `Dim MailUser` is written inside the `If` block, so it stops being usable outside of it (and if you compile you'll get an error on the line where you try to use it after the `If` block). By declaring the `MailUser` variable before the `If` block but assigning it's value inside of it, you get to keep it alive long enough to be able to actually use it.